# Использование API

Tags: веб-программирование, api

Интересует вопрос, имеет ли смысл создавать API и подгружать данные на сайт, используя запросы к этому API, ведь можно просто подгружать информацию с базы данных напрямую.

Большие компании предоставляют свои API, в которых собрана некая информация, для того чтобы этим могли пользоваться все кто пожелает, но есть ли смысл делать API для своих небольших сайтов, чтобы подгружать информацию оттуда, а не напрямую с базы данных?

Comment: В первую очередь вам надо было разобраться(прочитать) что такое API и когда его используют. API инструмент для взаимосвязи двух или более систем, для передачи и получения данных. Если у вас есть несколько сайтов и у каждого есть своя база данных, причём тут логика создания API? Какую информацию и куда бы хотели передать?

Comment: т.е API рационально использовать только для взаимодействия данных между разными сайтами?

Comment: Да, конечно, в идеале так )

Comment: Во-первых, прямой доступ к базе данных это как правило небезопасно (а что если DROP TABLE напишут?). Во-вторых, в будущем заменить базу данных не получится (все клиенты сломаются), а вот менять внутренности API можно сколько угодно, пока остаётся совместимый интерфейс

Comment: А что вы называете подгрузкой "напрямую из базы". Прямое обращение с сайта в БД в принципе невозможно, потому что БД не работает с HTTP

Comment: @Mike во-первых, существуют БД работающие по HTTP (правда, это обычно уже не SQL), а во-вторых, можно написать какой-нибудь простенький HTTP-прокси для проброса SQL-запросов (впрочем, это уже отдалённо начинает напоминать API)

Comment: Все зависит от силы и желания писать код. Под API нужно написать UI, на беке дополнительно код Сервисов + DB взаимодействие. И показывать эту инфу не всем пользователям а с какой-то определенной ролью. Вопрос один нужно ли вам это и если да то зачем?

Comment: Но есть ситуации когда может быть полезно такое :)